# Warning in dist(mat, method = distance) : NAs introduced by coercion Error in hclust(d, method = method): NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap using the function pheatmap(). But I get an error saying there are NA/NaN/Inf in the dataframe. I checkt it but there are no NA/NaN/Inf values in it..
This function worked before, so I do not see what I am doing wrong... Anyone any advise?

```
heat<-pheatmap(mat, kmeans_k = NA, breaks = NA, border_color= "grey60",cellwidth = 5, cellheight = 0.05, scale = "none", cluster_rows = TRUE,
         cluster_cols = TRUE, clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
         clustering_distance_cols = "euclidean", clustering_method = "complete",
         cutree_rows = 1, cutree_cols = 1,
         legend_labels = NA, annotation_row = NA, annotation_col = pd,
         annotation = pd, annotation_colors = anno_colors, annotation_legend = TRUE,
         annotation_names_row = TRUE, annotation_names_col = TRUE,
         drop_levels = TRUE, show_rownames = F, show_colnames = T, main = NA, fontsize = 4,
         fontsize_row = 4, fontsize_col = 4,
         display_numbers = F, number_format = "%.2f", number_color = "grey30",
         fontsize_number = 0.8 * fontsize, gaps_row = NULL, gaps_col = NULL,
         labels_row = NULL, labels_col = NULL, filename = NA, width = NA,
         height = NA, silent = FALSE)
```

```
Warning in dist(mat, method = distance) : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
```

Comment: You warning, then error, isn't saying the data.frame contains a 'NA', but the process of computing `dist` introduced NAs, that they then caused `hclust` to error. You could `debugonce(pheatmap)` and walk through to the dist process and see what fatal combination in your data is producing the NA. [dist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/dist) and look at the Value for how calculated as clue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the probable causes of these error and warnings is the presence of a non-numeric vector in the matrix `mat`.

For example, the first four columns in the `iris` data frame are numeric vectors, and the fifth one is a character vector. If you include all the columns as the input for `pheatmap`, the error and the warning message will pop up:

```
pheatmap(as.matrix(iris)) # failed.

#Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
#  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In dist(mat, method = distance) : NAs introduced by coercion
#2: In dist(mat, method = distance) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

If you include only the numeric columns, the function is executed with no error or warning

```
pheatmap(as.matrix(iris[,1:4]))  # succeeded.
```

Comment: unfortunatelyy this did not work..
```

Comment: Could you please share your code that you run and the error message that you got? I believe we'll get useful hints from there.